# Time complexity of algorithms 7^logn

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity

I have a question regarding time complexity. Is the time complexity of 7^logn in Θ(n) or Θ(n^n) or Θ(n^2) or something complety different? It confuses because the n is in the exponent. Thank you for your help

Comment: (*n* is in the exponent in *Θ(n^n)*, too.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a few [logarithmic identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Logarithmic_identities):

```
7^log(n) = 7^(log_7(n)/log_7(2)) = n^(1/log_7(2)) = n^log(7) ~= n^2.8
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can look on the following:

theta(n^2)=4^logn<7^logn<8^logn=2^3logn=theta(n^3)

Comment: This answer seems to be wrong. What do you for example when you say `theta(n^2)=4^logn`? First of all, `Theta(n^2)` is a set, not a number.

Comment: @Zabuzard the '=' sign is abuse of notation, its just a way to say that 4^logn is (belong to) theta(n^2) class. and about the estimation I did: I think its correct, look at the new answer to this thread

Comment: I just fail at correctly reading your answer. Maybe also format and highlight it a bit.

Comment: no problem, Its just I don't know how to do latex in this stack (using $..$ didn't work)

Comment: This stack unfortunately does not have LaTeX support :/